# Are any values naturally null or could they become null, in JavaScript, or are values only null when you manually set them null?

Tags: javascript, null

The title/headline pretty much says it all, but just wondering since I don't really use null (I just rely on undefined), but am still kind of a newbie so figured I should know this, and Google and SO both don't return any results for this, at least for me.

So, is anything naturally null, or could something become null without you setting it?  And if so, when?

Thank you. I appreciate you all reading this, also.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript will not set anything to `null` by itself; a programmer would have to do that.  Creating a variable without initializing a value will give you `undefined`.  Some frameworks or libraries may set things to `null`, but JavaScript will never do that by itself.

Answer (score 0):

I like thinking of null using the toilet paper example. Empty means you have no toilet paper left, null means you don't even have a roll.

With that said, when you create a variable in java script it requires you to initiate it in some way. So the only way a variable can become null is if it is set null or defined as null. This is true in java script and other java based languages, but not true for all programming languages.

Answer (score 0):

Null means an empty or non-existent value. Null is assigned and explicitly means nothing.
a null is also an object. this is actually a bug in  JavaScript implementation